# Permanent redirect my herokuapp domains endpoints to my custom domain in Flask

Tags: flask, heroku, dns

Here is what I tried till now

```
new_url = https://example.com

@app.route('/')
def root():
    return redirect(new_url, code=302)

@app.route('/<path:page>')
def anypage(page):
    return redirect('{new_url}/{page}'.format(page=page, new_url=new_url), code=302)
```

- It's only working for home and error handler pages in the development environment
- Error showing too many redirects in the production environment

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a .js file that always redirect you to your custom domain if it detects that the current URL is *.herokuapp.com.

You can do the below:

```js
var current_url = window.location.href
if (current_url == "your_app_name.herokuapp.com") {
    window.location.href = "yourcustomdomain";
}
```

Just make sure to include this with every HTML page, in the head.

Comment: Is there any method to do that with my backend file rather than templates?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.path.